# Uso de threads em C# sem armazenar em variável

Tags: c#, .net, thread

Se eu iniciar uma *thread* anonima:

```
new Thread(chat).Start();
```

e voltava a instancia-la desse mesmo modo, ela sobrepõem a outra *thread*? Se não, como deve dar um "kill" na primeira *thread* em questão.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não dá muito contexto, vou tentar adivinhar algumas coisas.

Cada vez que este código for chamado criará uma nova instância, ou seja, um novo objeto, portando uma nova *thread*. Elas não se confundem.

Desta forma não dá para ter nenhum controle sobre a instância já que não tem como se referenciar a ela. Se precisa disto, é muito simples, jogue em uma variável para ter uma referência no código. Não existe nenhum motivo pra não fazer isto.

Neste caso a *thread* terminará quando o método terminar sua execução, disponibilizando o objeto da *thread* para coleta posterior.

Mesmo que a instância estivesse "armazenada em uma variável", não deve "matá-la" diretamente. O que deveria ser feito é mandar uma instrução (através de uma variável que possa ser acessada de fora do método) para que o método pare de executar em condições normais. Tem um exemplo na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Ou pense em usar [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que é muito melhor que *thread* bruta.